# Policy classes for making widgets

Tags: c++, beginner, c++11

I have been learning C++ for the past few weeks, and I made my first try with policy classes. Ultimately my goal is to use policy classes to manufacture wrapper classes on an `std::vector`. Part of what the wrapper class does is generate a custom allocator class that depends on the policy classes.

That's the inspiration for what I have below, which is a widget maker that makes widgets with a printing function that depends on the templated inputs.

Printing policy classes:

```
template <class T>
struct Chatty
{
  static void logVal(T val){
    std::cout << val << std::endl;
  }
  static void logS(std::string s){
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
  }
};

template <class T>
struct Silent
{
  static void logVal(T val){}
  static void logS(std::string s){}
};
```

**`Widget`**:

```
class Widget {
public:
  int x;
  int y;
  std::function<void(std::string)> print;
  Widget()
    :x(0), y(0), print([](std::string){})
  {};
};
```

**`WidgetManager`**:

```
template < template <class Created> class CreationPolicy, template <class Created> class LoggingPolicy>
class WidgetManager : public CreationPolicy<Widget>, public LoggingPolicy<Widget>
{
public:
  WidgetManager() {};
  static Widget* doAll(){
    Widget* w = WidgetManager::Create();
    std::function<void(std::string)> f1 = WidgetManager::logS;
    w->print = WidgetManager::logS;
    return w;
  }
};
```

I would appreciate feedback on all aspects of the code, but I also have two specific questions:

1. My biggest concern: **is there a better way to assign functions to the Widgets I am making?** For example, perhaps I could directly assign member functions of `Widget`s from my `WidgetManager`, but then I'd have to bind the `WidgetMaker`'s `static` functions to individual instances of `Widget`s, which seems like more overhead. What's best performance-wise?
2. I am sure `WidgetManager::doAll()` is not the way to go, but I am struggling to **find another way to call functions from various policies all together**. What's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Widget`, the members `x` and `y` should be `private`.  They should not be exposed to the interface in such a way.  You can either add the `private` keyword above them, or just move the `public` keyword below them (members are `private` by default, so both are essentially the same).

Answer (score 2):

1. Consider using overload resolution to resolve the proper logging-method.

   - That allows you to template that member, and maybe use perfect forwarding.
2. Don't make useless costly copies. You can take arguments by `const&`.
3. Avoid `std::endl`, as constant flushing also flushes any chance of good performance down the drain.

```
struct Chatty {
    template<class T>
    static void log(T&& t) { std::cout << std::forward<T>(t) << '\n'; }
};
struct Silent {
    template<class T>
    static void log(T&&) {}
};
```

4. Your `WidgetMaker` is currently restricted to policies which are templates. That's a bad idea. Better accept a type-parameter like everyone else.
5. `doAll` assumes the logging-method is static. Why then do you assign it to a `std::function`? (Yes, that function should have a signature avoiding copies, but that's a separate problem.)

   The easiest way to repair that is using a lambda. Or you can get fancy with SFINAE and maybe also allow the policy-class to only implement those parts it wants to override.